# Distribute entity framework models over different assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model, entity-framework-6

Currently i am trying to use entity framework 6.3 with a kind of distributed models. My problem is, i want to seperate the models in different assemblies (for example the core application and plugins).

Now i'm search for a way, that my application get all models over reflection or some thing similar and register all models in the ef db context before startup.

Is this possible with entity framework 6?

Thank you.

Comment: You should consider to create a dbcontext for each module, and use It where you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for your models in every assembly over reflection.

Iterate through the AppDomain's assemblies and search for an attribute, interface or base class, see an example below.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");

    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
      var entityTypes = assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t =>
          t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PersistentAttribute), inherit: true)
          .Any());

      foreach (var type in entityTypes)
      {
        entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
          .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, i will try it instantly, great!

Comment: One more question, if i load the models dynamically, how to work with DbSet, becuase i have no collection regostered, which represents the Table in the Database.

Comment: You can call DbContext.Set<T> has the same effect as using the DbSet

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the perfect solution.

Comment: I know it's a bit old but I'm facing the same need, could you give some feedback on the way you got it working ?